How can I add "$" (Accounting Number Format) to the Excel 365 Quick Access Toolbar on Mac?
I want to add "$" (Accounting Number Format) to the Quick Access Toolbar (QAT) on Excel 365 on Mac. I can move it to the right column of the QAT customization dialog:

But when I click Save, the QAT is not changed, and "$" has been removed from the right column of the QAT customization dialog.
What do I need to do to get "$" added to the QAT on Mac? I don't have this problem on Windows (where I'm running Excel 2010). There adding "$" to the QAT works as expected.

If it's showing in the list as ABLE to be added, and then disappears, this seems to be a bug in the application. Make sure you're up to date, perhaps try a repair install, if that is a thing on MacOS, and submit a trouble ticket if none of that works, so that Microsoft can know this needs resolving.

There's no repair option for Mac, and updating the app didn't help. Sigh. I could tell MS about the problem, but my experience with MS is that there's no point. They do what they want to do, and they can't even be bothered to make it possible to move the QAT below the menu bar, which has been possible on Windows for at least 15 years.

They have a feedback tool for this purpose, and O365 is updated pretty frequently. Small bugs like this CAN and DO get quashed in patches, and often as a result of people reporting them.

Because the option IS showing in the dialog, but when you attempt to save or apply that setting no change is made and the setting appears reverted or reset when you reopen the dialog, this is an application issue.
Standard steps to resolve issues like this are:

Check for and install updates.
Uninstall and reinstall the software (if Repair isn't an option)

If neither of these work send Feedback to MS regarding the issue so they can add it to their list of bugs that need resolving.
